# How to inject aditional claims in Azure AD SSO Login in Blazor Server

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have Blazor Server apps. I have a SSO (Azure Active Directory) login feature. After login with SSO I get some claims which is been set in the Azure Active Directory. But after login I would like to set some aditiional claims. So I have these below code in the **MainLayout.razor.cs** file.

```
[Inject] UserManager<AppUser> UserManager { get; set; }

 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
 {
    string username = "testuser@email.com";
    var createdUser = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(username);                            
    await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(createdUser, new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Adminstrator"));
 }
```

And in every razor page, I have the below authorize attribute to secure the page to view.

```
@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "Adminstrator")]
```

But even after injecting the role I can not access the page. I checked and found that the claim with role is not injected.

Can anyone tell me how to selve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(defaultUser, Roles.Admin.ToString());